# Is possible to setup a wifi hotspot that uses wpa enterprise on a non rooted android device

Tags: wifi-hotspot

Android stock wifi hotspot settings page only allows for WPA2-PSK authentication. I was wondering if there is a way to have WPA-Enterprise PEAP authentication where I can just enter the address and port of a remote radius server. Also, if possible, I would like to do this on a non-rooted android phone.